# How Express routes similar url links?

Tags: node.js, express

Developing web app with node.js and express.

I have following two urls to distinguish:

1. /api/v1/source?id=122323
2. /api/v1/source?timestamp=1555050505&count=10

I come up a naive solution. I leave such similar urls to one route method and use `if eles` to specify solutions, i.e:

```
if(id){
//solution with id 
}

if(timestamp&&count){
//solution with timestamp and count but without id 
}
```

Apparently, this is not clean. Because in the future,I may want to add new field which will make this router huge and ugly.

So How can I overcome this? Or to change url structure.I want to build a Restful api.

Comment: I would recommend having multiple routes to the same path, and if the conditions aren't met, call the optional argument `next()` to allow the next route handler to process the unhandled request. Doing this will at least allow you to break up the logic more clearly at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put together all the properties in a list and use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all the values in Array evaluates to true.

Maybe something like this:

```js
(( /* req, res */)=>{
  // Dummy express Request Object
  const req = {
    params : {
      //id : '123',
      count : 10,
      timestamp : 1555050505,
      newParameter : 'whatever value'
    }
  }

  let { params } = req;

  let {
      id
    , count
    , timestamp
    , newParameter
  } = params;


  if(id){
    console.log('Action with id');
    return;
  }

  let secondConditionArray = [
    count, timestamp, newParameter
  ];


  if( secondConditionArray.every(Boolean) ){
    console.log('Second Action')
  } else {
    console.log('Some values are no truthy')
  }
})()
```

Comment: Yes! You're right! I'll edit to fit my anwser with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Url parameters with `req.params`

```
if(req.params.id){
//solution with id 
}

if(req.params.timestamp && req.params.count){
//solution with timestamp and count but without id 
}
```

Comment: Actually,this is exactly what i came up with, already in my question.